# use my selected \sffamily fonts for \mathfs

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to use my selected sans serif font in place of my mathfs fonts. I know that there are so called mathversions which define different types of characters (letters, symbols, etc).
I would be satisfied if I could set the basic Latin alphabetical math sans serif characters the same as my default text sans serif font. Is it possible, how?

Comment: If David Carlisle's answer does not solve the problem, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which shows the font configuration you are using. We do not even know if you are using (pdf)TeX or Lua/XeTeX or which font or in which encoding(s).

Comment: His solution is working perfectly in my configuration (using pdflatex, Latin-1 encoding, and tex gyre fonts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\mathsf` is defined by

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
```

so you just need

```
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{normal}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
```

with `cmss` replaced by the LaTeX font family name of the font you want.